# Get all the values of an element in the incoming XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

Good day!
How to go through the incoming text and get all the values of the "Call" element

```
IN:
<text:One>
   <text:Collections>
     <text:Call>
        <text:Name>TEST1</text:Name>
     </text:Call>
     <text:Call>
        <text:Name>TEST2</text:Name>
     </text:Call>
  </text:Collections>
</text:One>
```

How to get the output (using X-Path):

```
OUT:
...
<string name="Call" value "TEST1,TEST2"/>
...
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i do: ....<xsl:atribute name="Call">....
           ...<xsl:value-of select="one/Collections/Call"/>
       </xsl:atribute name="Call">  but I only get <string name="Call" value "TEST1"/>

Comment: Your input is not a well-formed XML document: you cannot use a prefix without binding to a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<One>
   <Collections>
     <Call>
        <Name>TEST1</Name>
     </Call>
     <Call>
        <Name>TEST2</Name>
     </Call>
  </Collections>
</One>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/One">
    <string name="Call">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:for-each select="Collections/Call">
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string name="Call" value="TEST1,TEST2"/>
```